# I can't succeed to correctly handle exceptions in NestJs

Tags: rest, exception, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to learn NestJs by creating a CRUD API.
I've created my controller, module, service etc...

And created a get users/id endpoint. Everything worked fine, and I decided to add some security.
I want to check if the id is not null and is a string. If not, I want to throw an exception (bad request) + console.log a message.
I also want to check if when I look for a user with a good if, the user exists. if not, throw a not found exception.

Here is my service:

```
async findOne(id: string): Promise<IUser | null> {
    if (id === null || typeof id !== 'string') {
      throw new BadRequestException('Id must be a string');
    }
    const user = await this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    if (user === null) {
      throw new NotFoundException('No user found for this id');
    }
    return user;
  }
```

and controller:

```
@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param('id') id: string) {
    try {
      return await this.userService.findOne(id);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof BadRequestException) {
        throw new HttpException(
          {
            status: HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
            error: 'This is a custom message',
          },
          HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
          {
            cause: error,
          },
        );
      } else if (error instanceof NotFoundException) {
        throw new HttpException(
          {
            status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            error: 'This is a custom not found message',
          },
          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
          {
            cause: error,
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I try a get request with .../users/1111 ,I got a 200 response. And when I try with a good id (a string) but with no user linked, I also get a 200 response.

I don't understand why.. Can you help me please ?
I also want to log the message.

And have you any advices ? Is the right way (standard + elegant) to do ?

Thanks guys ;)

EDIT:
Here is my controller:

```
@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param('id') { id }: IdDto) {
    try {
      return await this.userService.findOne(id);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof NotFoundException) {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      } else {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      }
    }
  }
```

my service:

```
async findOne(id: string): Promise<IUser | null> {
    const user = await this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    if (user === null) {
      throw new NotFoundException('No user found for this id');
    }
    return user;
  }
```

my dto:

```
import { IsString, IsNotEmpty, IsMongoId } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

export class IdDto {
  @IsMongoId()
  id: string;
}
```

And when I search .../users/aaaa  or /users/63ecf079c305ac977da87bcb (valid mongo id) or ...users/1111 I get:
{
"statusCode": 400,
"message": [
"id must be a mongodb id"
],
"error": "Bad Request"
}

and I don't know why...

I really want to test if the id is valid + test if the user exist (if the id is valid).
What should I do ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are checking id to be of a type string and not null. Technically any param is a string, so even `1111` becomes `"1111"`. You can verify that by logging it like so `console.log({ id })` (expected result: `{ id: "1111" }`).

For the validation I would suggest to follow the documentation on validation pipes: [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation).

**TLDR;**
The following code will add a global pipe to validate payloads
`app.module.ts` (copied from [NestJS | Pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#global-scoped-pipes))

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_PIPE } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useClass: ValidationPipe,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

To make it work you will need to have `class-validator` and `class-transformer` installed, so run:

```bash
npm i --save class-validator class-transformer
```

Then declare a class that will serve as a blueprint of a DTO (Data Transfer Object), like so:

```
import { IsString, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class IdDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  id: string;
}
```

Then in your controller use the `IdDto`:

```
@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param() { id }: IdDto) {
    ...
```

This already should be enough to have a basic validation. Moreover, this will convert the payload to a format that you expect (or fail and throw validation error). It is done via `plainToClass` method exposed from `class-transformer`. So there won't be any surprises with JavaScript type coercion like `"1" + 1 = "11"`.

If you need to format your exceptions (or enrich them with additional data) you can use exception filters. There is a nice documentation about it in the [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1).

Hope that helps!

#### Edit

Remove the `try ... catch` block in your controller.
Like so:

```
@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param('id') id: string) {
      return await this.userService.findOne(id);
  }
```

In your current code there is a fallthrough case. You are checking for the error being `instanceof NotFoundException` or `instanceof BadRequestException`. So if it will be an instance of `HttpException` there is no case for that, so the error is caught and controller sends an empty `200` response.

Comment: But when I do that, when I try with ..../users/aaa I got the error message. And how can I test if a user exist ?

Comment: If the database query returns null you need to throw `NotFoundException`. You already have the needed logic in `user.service` in `findOne` method.

Isn't the desired behavior? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hey :) First, I need to check if an Id is valid (mongo id) when we consume the API endpoint users/... , the Id need to be valid. Furthermore, I also want to test if the db query returns null, then throw the NotFoundException. But how to actually catch this in my controller ?

Comment: For the id validation you can use `@IsMongoId()` decorator. But why do you need to catch it in the controller? Isn't it logical to throw the `404` directly? In case you throw an error anywhere in the code during the request it will be correctly sent to the client. Please, take a look at the [NestJS Documentation Page](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters).

TLDR; you don't need to worry about error, just throw and forget. If you need to format an error you can use `ExceptionFilters`

Comment: Look at my other question for IsMongoId() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509265/problem-with-ismongoid-class-validator-nestjs please :) Because I want to throw different exceptions and add custom message :) But for example I tested with a good id but that is not linked to an user, and I've got 0 error, just a 200 status..

Comment: Remove try catch block form the controller. just `return await this.userService.findOne(id)`. I think you receive an empty response with status 200, right? If so that means that `if` statements are not matched. You can validate it by adding `else { throw new Error('Uncaught error') }` condition.

Comment: I don't understand .. what should I do with the user service and user controller + id dto ?

Comment: Alright, I've modified my controller as you said:@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param('id') { id }: IdDto) {
    return await this.userService.findOne(id);
  } and my service: async findOne(id: string): Promise<IUser | null> {
    const user = await this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    if (user === null) {
      throw new NotFoundException('No user found for this id');
    }
    return user;
  } but when I try with /63ecf079c305ac977da87bcb I got "statusCode": 400,
"message": [
"id must be a string"
],

Comment: Based on the updated code, I have no idea where `id must be a string` comes from. `@IsMongoId` throws this error: `id must be a mongodb id`, so it's not it. Can you verify that you saved the code and the code with the latest changes is run? Easiest way to do so would be to stop the server, delete `./dist` folder and start the server.

Comment: Now it trowing "it must be a mongodb id" , but don't understand because it's actually a valid mongo id..

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the answer. It should be `@Param()` without `id` (`controller` code). Sorry about that. Please try it out, should be resolved now