# Problem with IsMongoID() class-validator NestJs

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, class-validator

I try to use a class-validator on a DTO to check if an id is valid or not.

Here is my controller:

```
@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param('id') { id }: IdDto) {
    try {
      return await this.userService.findOne(id);
    } catch (error) {}
  }
```

and my Dto:

```
import { IsString, IsNotEmpty, IsMongoId } from 'class-validator';
import { Type, Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class IdDto {
  @IsMongoId()
  id: string;
}
```

the prolem is when I try to search for a valid user, for example: http://localhost:3000/users/63ecf079c305ac977da87bcb

I got this error:

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"message": [
"id must be a mongodb id"
],
"error": "Bad Request"
}
```

and I don't know why because it's a valid mongo id...

Can you help me please ?

And furthermore, I want to add a validation in my service:

```
async findOne(id: string): Promise<IUser | null> {
    const user = await this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    if (user === null) {
      throw new NotFoundException('No user found for this id');
    }
    return user;
  }
```

I want to check if the user exists or not, if we look for a user (with a valid id) but there is no user, I want to throw an exception, and catch it in my controller.
How can i do it correcly ?
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let me provide you with short and clear answer:

**First**, update your controller to use validation pipe with **whitelist: true** validation pipe option. It should fix the problem:

```
@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })) { id }: IdDto) {
    try {
      return await this.answerService.findOne(id);
    } catch (error) {}
  }
```

Note: this will automatically remove non-whitelisted properties (those without any decorator in the validation class), refer to : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#stripping-properties

**Second**, this [article](https://dev.to/antoncodes/nestjs-stop-handling-errors-like-this-2446) is helpful for you to decide how to handle the exception when no user is found.